# SCA to Listview with OnClickListener not getting the String Value of the cursor

Tags: android, listview

I need help here, I got a SCA into the ListView but then when I applied OnClickListener to get the String Value on my ListView it shows text but not the actual text that is on my ListView android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2915f605.

here is my Java File in displaying the ListView.

```
    package com.example.jello.letscook;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class showmenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Spinner mainIng;
    EditText sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6;
    CheckBox Cb_Ar,Cb_Db,Cb_Hb;
    String toPass="";
    ListView myList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showmenu);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

         sub1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sub1);
         sub2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sub2);
         sub3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sub3);
         sub4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sub4);
         sub5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sub5);
         sub6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sub6);
        Cb_Ar = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
        Cb_Db = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check2);
        Cb_Hb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check3);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selectView);

            myDb.insertHB(true);
            myDb.inert_Arth(true);
            myDb.inert_Dia(true);
        myDb.checkData(StartingScreen.gettingCheckBox());

        showList();

    }

    public void showList() {

        String toPass;
        toPass = StartingScreen.gettingCheckBox();
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getData(toPass);
        String[] fromField = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.RECIPE_NAME};
        int[] toView = new int[] {R.id.textViewMenuSuggest};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.menushow,cursor,fromField,toView,0);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                int itemPos = position;
                Cursor listValue = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition(itemPos);
                Toast.makeText(showmenu.this, "" + listValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my XML Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Menu to Cook:"
        android:id="@+id/lala"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/selectView"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think your error comes from Crusor because you dont parse properly values from DB.. can you try some like this after declare Cursor               String col=listValue .getString(listValue .getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_COL));

Comment: it errors the col  after the String.

Comment: hmm did you replace DBHelper and KEY_COL with your variables

Comment: Already done, and it worked :) Thank you for the help :)

Comment: If you want i can put as a answer and you can accept it? If my asnwer help you of course !

Comment: Yes sure sir my pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error comes from Crusor because you dont parse properly values from DataBase.. can you try some like this after line that you  declare `Cursor`
put this line

```
 String someData=listValue .getString(listValue .getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_COL));
```

`DbHelper` is your DataBase variable, also `KEY_COL` is your column from which you fetch desire data.Hope to help!